# Need Help Implementing Ads With Admob and Android Studio

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, android-studio

I integrated Admob SDK into my application and then initlialized the SDK in my Main Activity, I'm having trouble implementing my ads though and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can someone point me in the correct direction of what I'm missing? Thank You.

Here is the Main Activity java file:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAdLoadCallback;

import org.apache.cordova.*;


public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity {

    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Initialize AdMob
        MobileAds.initialize(this, initializationStatus -> {
            // Load the interstitial ad
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            InterstitialAd.load(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest, new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded(InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                    mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                }

            });
        });

        // enable Cordova apps to be started in the background
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null && extras.getBoolean("cdvStartInBackground", false)) {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }

        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
    }

    private void showInterstitial() {
        // Show the ad if it's ready
        if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
            mInterstitialAd.show(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code to show the ad in the HTML:

```
      <script>
        var interstitialAd = null;
        var adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712"; // Replace with your ad unit ID
        var adLoadCallback = function () {
            // The ad has finished loading, show it now
            if (interstitialAd) {
                interstitialAd.show();
            }
        };
        var adErrorCallback = function (error) {
            // Failed to load the ad, log the error
            console.error(error);
        };
        var adRequest = new window.adsbygoogle.AdRequest();
        var adSlot = new window.adsbygoogle.AdSlot(adUnitId, {fullWidth: true, autoRefresh: false});
        var adManager = new window.adsbygoogle.AdManager(adRequest, [adSlot]);
        adManager.load().then(function (ads) {
            // The ads have finished loading, get the interstitial ad
            interstitialAd = ads[0].getInterstitialAd();
            if (interstitialAd) {
                interstitialAd.onLoad(adLoadCallback);
                interstitialAd.onFail(adErrorCallback);
            }
        }).catch(adErrorCallback);
    </script>
```